# Deck transformations on $S^1\times \mathbb{R}P^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, covering-spaces, cw-complexes

I'm studying for qualifying exams and stuck on the following problem:

Suppose that $S^1\times \mathbb{R}P^2$ covers a space, and let $h$ be a deck transformation of the covering. Show that the induced isomorphism $h_*$ of $H_1(S^1\times \mathbb{R}P^2)$ is the identity.

I have made several attempts to solve it with no success. For example, if we can show that $h$ has a fixed point, we will be done. Alternatively, by looking at $\operatorname{Aut}(H_1(S^1\times \mathbb{R}P^2))\cong \mathbb{Z}_2^2$ and applying Lefschetz, we can show that $h_*$ is neither automorphism that maps $(1,0)\mapsto (-1,0)$. However, it remains to eliminate the possibility that $h_*$ is the automorphism that maps $(1,0)\mapsto (1,1)$ and $(0,1)\mapsto (0,1)$. Will either of these methods work? Does anyone know of a slicker proof?

Comment: You won't show that $h$ has a fixed point, because $S^1 \times RP^2$ covers itself via the map $p(\theta, P) = (2\theta, P)$, and the map $h(\theta, P) = (\theta + \pi, P)$ is a deck transformation without fixed points.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Induced map on homology from a covering space isomorphism](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383773/induced-map-on-homology-from-a-covering-space-isomorphism). (That question was not fully answered.)

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena: So which question do you think should be closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that the automorphism you are worried about is induced by a homeomorphism $h\in Homeo(S^1\times RP^2)$. Then a lift of $h$ to the universal cover conjugates an orientation-preserving deck-transformation to an orientation-reversing one, which is impossible. Hence, you are done.

Edit: Set $M=S^1\times RP^2$. I will identify $\pi_1(M)$ with the group of automorphisms of the universal cover $\tilde M\to M$. The group $\pi_1(M)$ splits as the product $Z\times Z_2$; let $a, b$ denote respective generators of the two direct factors. Then $a$ preserves orientation (of the universal cover $\tilde M$) while $b$ reverses orientation. In particular, $a+b$ also reverses the orientation. Therefore, a homeomorphism of $\tilde M$ cannot conjugate $a$ to $a+b$ (conjugation is understood in the group $Homeo(\tilde M)$). This is a general fact about homeomorphisms of oriented manifolds $X$: For $f_i\in Homeo(X)$, $i=1,2$, the homeomorphism 
$$
f_1 f_2 f_1^{-1} 
$$
preserves orientation of $X$ if and only if $f_2$ does.

It follows that every $h\in Homeo(M)$ has to preserve the above direct product decomposition of $\pi_1(M)\cong H_1(M)$.

Comment: Why can we lift an automorphism of this space to it's universal cover? Being an automorphism, it induces an automorphism of the fundamental group, hence cannot satisfy the lifting criterion.

Comment: I'm very confused by this. Which deck transformations do you mean get conjugated? Is one of them the original $h$? If so, what does it mean for it to be orientation preserving or reversing when $S^1 \times \mathbb{RP}^2$ is not orientable?

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena: I am not using the assumption that $h$ was a deck-transformation, I am referring to the elements of $\pi_1(S^1\times RP^2)$ acting as deck-transformations on $R\times S^2$ (the universal cover). Then one (every) lift of $h$ conjugates them in the group $Homeo(R\times S^2)$.

Comment: @thyde641: That's a good exercise to work out when preparing for your qual: Every homeomorphism $f:X\to X$ lifts to a homeomorphism $\tilde{f}: \tilde{X}\to \tilde{X}$ of the universal cover (lift first to $\tilde{X}\to X$ and then use homotopy lifting property as $\tilde{X}$ is simply connected). Then you check that the lift $\tilde{f}$ will satisfy $\tilde f G \tilde f^{-1}=G$, where $G$ is the group of automorphisms of the universal cover $p$. In the case when $G$ is abelian, conjugation by $\tilde f$ is the same automorphism  of $G$ as the one defined by $\pi_1(f): \pi_1(X)\to \pi_1(X)$.

Comment: ...In the nonabelian case, the same is true modulo some inner automorphisms of $G$.

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena: There are two ways to define which elements $g$ of $\pi_1(M)$ are orientation-preserving/reversing. If you work in the smooth category, you just say that $g$ preserves orientation iff one/every smooth loop in $M$ representing $g$ has trivial normal bundle. If you prefer the topological category, you can define it by looking at the action of $g$ on $H_c^n(\tilde{M})\cong Z$, where $n=dim(M)$ and $\tilde M$ is the universal cover of $M$. Then $g$ preserves orientation iff it acts as the identity on the infinite cyclic group $Z$...

Comment: ... Yet another way to do it is by looking at the induced maps of local homology groups $H_n(\tilde M, \tilde M\setminus m)$, for points $m\in \tilde{M}$. All these homology groups are canonically isomorphic to $Z$ (use the excision to get a canonical isomorphism). This gives you an action of $Homeo(\tilde M)$ (in particular, of $g\in \pi_1(M)$) on the infinite cyclic group $Z$. Then a homeomorphism $g\in Homeo(\tilde M)$ preserves orientation iff the above action is the identity...

Comment: Here, of course, I identify the fundamental group and the group of deck-transformations/automorphisms of the universal cover of $M$.

Comment: Thanks for expanding the answer, I understand now. Just to be explicit about it you could add a sentence to your answer saying that if for a class $a \in \pi_1(M,x_0)$, $\tau_{a,x_0} : \tilde{M} \to \tilde{M}$ denotes the corresponding deck transformation on the universal cover; then for any $h \in Homeo(M)$ with lift $\tilde{h} \in Homeo(\tilde{M})$ you have that $\tilde{h} \circ \tau_{a,x_0} \circ \tilde{h}^{-1} = \tau_{h_\ast(a), h(x_0)}$. (That is what you meant, right?)

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena: Exactly, just you do not have to worry about base-points in this example since $\pi_1$ is abelian.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the additional details. This helps a lot!