# Basic question about lifting maps to covering spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Any continuous map $f: X_1 \to X_2$ "lifts" to a map $\tilde f: \tilde X_1 \to \tilde X_2$ (provided that $X_1$ and $X_2$ have universal covers).

The space $\tilde X_1$ is certainly path-connected and locally path-connected and we have
$$(f\circ p_1)_*(\pi_1(\tilde X_1))=\{0\}=(p_2)_*(\pi_1(\tilde X_2)).$$
Then the lifting criterion ensures the existence of a lift $\ \tilde f: \tilde X_1 \to \tilde X_2$. Is this a very basic fact I somehow forgot, or have I made some glaring error?

Comment: Certainly one can lift in this manner. I'm not sure I understand what the question is.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Thanks for the sanity check.  My question was simply whether or not the statement (and my justification) was correct.  I suppose I just never saw any applications of this fact when I first learned about covering spaces.

Comment: No problem. I don't think I've seen an application of this at all; if you have one in mind, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @MikeMiller: It was used by studiosus [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910308/deck-transformations-on-s1-times-mathbbrp2) in the context of lifting a homeomorphism $f: X\to X$ to a homeomorphism $\tilde f: \tilde X \to \tilde X$.