# Explicit form of a lift $\tilde f: \tilde X_1 \to \tilde X_2$ of a continuous map $f: X_1 \to X_2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is embarrassingly simple for most, but I am a High School student trying to teach myself, and I am having trouble figuring it out:

In the post [Basic question about lifting maps to covering spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912119/basic-question-about-lifting-maps-to-covering-spaces) it is claimed that  any continuous map $f: X_1 \to X_2$ "lifts" to a map $\tilde f: \tilde X_1 \to \tilde X_2$ (provided that $X_1$ and $X_2$ have universal covers).

I tried, but I am having trouble finding an explicit form for the map $ \tilde f$ by trying to cook up commutative diagrams and using lifting properties.

I looked for related answers and it seems we can also use deck transformations and
conjugation properties of the group of deck transformations, but I still feel stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a projection $p_1: \tilde X_1 \to X_1$, so first write $g = fp_1: \tilde X_1 \to X_2$. Now $\tilde X_1$ is simply connected, so this lifts to the universal cover of $X_2$; call the lift $\tilde f: \tilde X_1 \to \tilde X_2$. So we have a commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\tilde X_1 @>\tilde f >> \tilde X_2\\
@Vp_1 VV @Vp_2 VV\\
X_1 @>f>> X_2
\end{CD}$$

as desired.

Comment: Reference: The section in Hatcher on covering spaces, Prop 1.33.

Comment: I see, so we should have $p_2 \circ \tilde f =p_1 f $ ?

Comment: @user201980 Yes; that's precisely what we mean by a lift in this context.

Comment: @MikeMiller: Just curious, can we isolate $\tilde f $, or it must be given in an equality like the one I wrote? It seems like a strange way of defining.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, @user201980. There are many possible lifts of $f$ (precisely $\pi_1(X_2)$-many, if $X_2$ is connected), all depending on where you lift some particular point.

Comment: (I wrote down the maps in the wrong order; it should be read $p_2\tilde f = fp_1$.)