# Lifting a holomorphic map between Complex Tori to the Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

Given a holomorphic map $$\phi:\frac{\mathbb{C}}{\Lambda}\to\frac{\mathbb{C}}{\Lambda'}$$

My aim is to lift it to a holomorphic map $\Phi:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$. The author has hinted to use the lifting property for this.

I know that if $\tilde{X}$ is a covering space of $X$ then any map $f:Y\to X$ can be lifted to a map $\tilde{f}:Y\to\tilde{X}$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is the covering space of any complex tori with covering map being the canonical projection map (correct me if I'm wrong). Hence my aim is to find a holomorphic $\Phi$ such that the diagram commutes.

$$\begin{array}
A\mathbb{C} & \stackrel{\Phi}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb{C} \\
\downarrow{p_1} & & \downarrow{p_2} \\
\frac{\mathbb{C}}{\Lambda} & \stackrel{\phi}{\longrightarrow} & \frac{\mathbb{C}}{\Lambda'}  
\end{array}
$$
How do I proceed? Thank you.

**Edit:** I recently checked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081984/explicit-form-of-a-lift-tilde-f-tilde-x-1-to-tilde-x-2-of-a-continuous-ma?noredirect=1&lq=1). How can we show that the lift of this holomorphic function will be holomorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you linked gives us the existence of the map you want. For it to be holomorphic it is enough to see that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are holomorphic and locally biholomorphic.

Comment: But if $p_1$ is holomorphic and doubly periodic, it will turn out to be constant, right?

Comment: You are defining the complex structure on the tori using the functions $p_1$ and $p_2$. They are just coordinates on the manifolds and the function $\phi$ is going to be holomorphic with respect to the coordinates $p_1$ and $p_2$. 
No $p_1$ and $p_2$ are not constants, liuville's theorem doesn't apply here.

Comment: I am having a major crisis in my head (I tried visualizing the map which seems wrong now). How do I proceed to show that $p_1$ is holomorphic? Maybe that'll give me some ideas.

Comment: So what you need to show that $p_1$ is holomorphic is that for any point $z\in\mathbb{C}$ then there are open sets $U,V$. $U$ a neighborhood of $z$, $V$ a neighborhood of $p_1(z)$ and a chart $\psi:V\to W$ ($W$ a subset of $\C$ and $\psi$ a homeomorphism). Then $p_1$ is holomorphic at $z$ if $\psi\circ\p_1|U:U\to W$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Pressed enter too quickly, dont know how to edit my comment. But anyway,

Comment: $p_1$ being a covering map means it kinda gives canonical coordinates on the torus, that is the charts are local inverses of $p_1$, so $p_1$ will be a holomorphic map by construction.

Comment: I get it now. Finally how do I conclude that the said two conditions imply that the the lift is holomophic? Does it follow from the fact that $\Phi(z)=p_2^{-1}\phi p_1(z)$ $\forall z\in \Phi(\mathfrak{B}_r(z))$ (using local biholomorphic-ness of $p_2$)?

Comment: Yes exactly. And all 3 of those maps are locally holomorphic.